Ansible: how to filter json value based on another json value?
I have a query that returns:
ok: [oc-ar-ar-test-ansible-api] => {
    "ivr_list.json": [
        {
            "announcement": {
                "id": "0",
                "name": "None"
            },
            "dests": {
                "i": {
                    "id": "101",
                    "name": "Pablo Gonzalez",
                    "type": "Extension"
                },
                "t": {
                    "id": "100",
                    "name": "Fruta Peralta",
                    "type": "Extension"
                }
            },
            "id": "3",
            "loops": "2",
            "name": "Prueba",
            "timeout": "10"
        },
        {
            "announcement": {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "General-ES"
            },
            "dests": {
                "i": {
                    "id": "10000",
                    "name": "General",
                    "type": "Queue"
                },
                "t": {
                    "id": "10000",
                    "name": "General",
                    "type": "Queue"
                }
            },
            "id": "23",
            "loops": "2",
            "name": "General-ES",
            "timeout": "10"
        }
    ]
}

I need to get the "id" based on the IVR name. For example:
If the name of the IVR is "General-ES", it must return the "id" 23.
Could you help me on how to solve it, I haven't found a way to do it yet?
I did many tests but I couldn't do it, either it always returned a single ID no matter what name I entered, or I didn't get anything.

What is the "IVR name"? What have you tried? Please provide an explicitly description of the logic you're trying to implement.

You want to investigate the selectattr filter of Jinja, where your expression would probably look something like (my_json_data | selectattr('name', '==', 'General-ES')).0.id.

Thank you very much for responding, you helped me solve the problem.
Here I leave the lines of code with which I solved that issue.
- name: test1
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ivr_list.json | json_query(jmesquery) | selectattr('Name',     'equalto', 'General-ES') | map(attribute='Id') | list }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[*].{Name: name, Id: id}"
  register: ivr_filter_id
  tags:
    - test

